# How to generate a QR code from WeChat user id?

Tags: qr-code, wechat

I want to be able to input a WeChat user id and somehow be able to generate the corresponding WeChat QR code on the screen.. is this possible and if so how do you do it?

Comment: Can you form the url from the user id? Then use a qr generator with that url.

Comment: Didn't think of that.. however a) don't know what the URL would be / how to find it and b) how do I know that WeChat uses a URL based QR code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

3 years ago, you can generate QR code from URL: `http://open.weixin.qq.com/qr/code/?username=<wechat_id>`. However, this API is unavailable now. It seems Tencent disabled this interface due to security consideration -- this API can be easily abused to send spam invitation.

If you speak Chinese, please check https://www.zhihu.com/question/21384291 for discussion on this topic in history.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create your own QR code for your WeChat profile, you must first download the current QR code of your profile in WeChat.
Go to your profile, go to “My QR Code” and select the three dots in the top right corner, select “Save Image”. 
The QR code is now stored in your photo album.
[Screenshot: How to get WeChat QR Code for your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiqdU.jpg)

Before you can create your own QR code, you must decode the URL to your profile from the downloaded QR code. To do so use the ZXing decoder.

Upload your QR code there and you will receive the URL that is behind the QR Code. Now you can use this URL to create a QR code for your profile.

In the following post you see detailed description how to create QR Codes for your profile or for official WeChat acccounts:
https://blog.qrd.by/2018/06/05/create-designer-wechat-qr-codes-for-official-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

As it was written above, you can't create QR code by means of user ID, but you can use your QR code to generate a web-page containing a link to your WeChat profile using https://msng.link.

This can help to show links to your messengers in social network sites. This should take just a minute, I've made a video instruction for you here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db8eNHSuSXM